# Field Taxonomy Reference full view

Tags: taxonomy-terms

is this possible to create full view formatter for taxonomy reference field? I've tried default formatters but it only prints title of the term and nothing else...

Comment: what else is there to print?

Comment: I've added custom fields

Comment: custom fields to the node or the taxonomy term?

Comment: I've added fields to the taxonomy type

Answer (score 0):

I see.

Try this, create a view of fields of content type (ie: Articles)

In your view, under Advanced, RELATIONSHIPS, add taxonomy terms on node.

[image]

Now under FIELDS add a field, and now you should have access to the tax term fields now.

Comment: I want to display term on node via field term reference.

Comment: Then add a term reference relationship instead of taxonomy terms on node.